# How do I add a value to an existing hash?

Tags: c#, hash

For instance, I do an MD5 of "hashable" using:

```
        protected string hexHashMD5(byte[] filePart) {
        // Now that we have a byte array we can ask the CSP to hash it
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(filePart);

        // Build the final string by converting each byte
        // into hex and appending it to a StringBuilder
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++) {
            sb.Append(result[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        // And return it
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and store it's output into a string variable in my program.  How can I take that Hash and add another byte[] to create a new hash?

I've been told that you can use file stream, to automatically stream in a bit at a time, and make the full hash, but what happens when I need to hash two separate files together?

Comment: Whaaat? Do you want to calculate md5(a concat b) or md5(a) concat md5(b)?

Comment: I need to calculate byte[] b = byte[4096] hash, then concatenate byte[] c = byte[4096], up to 2,118 times (so far).  Ending up with only 1 hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom `Stream` class that reads the two streams in order, then pass that to `ComputeHash`.

Alternatively, you can read both streams one block at a time and pass each block to `TransformBlock`:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true) {
    int read = stream1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read == 0) break;
    hash.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, read, null, 0);
}

while (true) {
    int read = stream2.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read == 0) break;
    hash.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, read, null, 0);
}

hash.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);
var hashCode = hash.Hash;
```

Comment: Yes. `TransformBlock` is really handy for stuff like this.

Comment: This looks like it may work, but the issue I am running into is more that I have files of a large size (over 4GB as large, currently, as 8.5 GB) and I am running into memory issues attempting to hash the file all at once.  Lastly, what does the variable hash stand for in your code, or is it a default present when including a certain object?

A co-worker mentioned thinking that you could "append to" or "sequentially create" a hash.  Thus, the initial question of adding to an existing hash.

Comment: @James: This code will only ever load 4K in-memory at once.  This is how to sequentially build a hash.

Comment: @SLaks: Still, what does the hash variable represent?  I don't see it declared.  Er go, what type of object is it?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out after starting up VS this morning.  Every hash algorithm has the option of TransformBlock.

Comment: The only thing I would add, to someone new to hashing coming to this page is to run the string builder from my original example on var hashCode as a replacement for the variable result.  This way you get a readable hash instead of a byte[].